# AWS: Assign tag to secret using variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

I want to assign variable's value to the secret. I tried this.
`aws secretsmanager tag-resource --secret-id blah-blah --tags '[{"Key": "abc", "Value": "{$a}"}]'`

I'm getting this error:
`An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the TagResource operation: Request rejected by the downstream tagging service. Please check that you're only using allowed characters.`

Any help with this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong characters and quotes. It should be:

```
aws secretsmanager tag-resource --secret-id blah-blah --tags '[{"Key": "abc", "Value": "'${a}'"}]'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and this was the only exact hit on Google. For future seekers **this error indictes an error on the tags**, not the secrets. It kind of say in the error message, but still took me some time to figure out.

We missed a `!sub` for substitution on the tags on the bottom line when trying to define this in SAM:

```
  Auth0TokenSecret:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties:
      Name: 'auth0/aws-client-secret'
      Description: 'Auth0 token'
      SecretString: !Ref Auth0Token
      Tags:
        - Key: AppName
          Value: ${AWS::StackName}
```